# Website has a strange string at the end of URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm making a website using WordPress running on an Apache server.. At the end of my URL, I get a random string of characters, and I've got no idea why they're there or where they came from, I asked my hosting provider to see if they could shed any light on the situation, but they came back with nothing more than "I don't know ask someone else". The string changes for each different device I use, the one I get when I use my computer is `?v=79cba1185463`.

I'm completely at a loss with this now, I've tried looking for a redirect command in the .htaccess file, but I don't really know much code, basic IF statements is my limit really, and I've tried using a plugin to manage redirects to see if it's a redirect problem, but the plugin didn't work.

I would really appreciate any input on this and a fix if possible. It's driving me round the bend.

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/204937/why-v-hash-is-added-to-my-urls

Comment: Thank you so much, solved the problem, I've been pulling my hair out about this (so has my boss).